# Variable inputs into a function in Pymongo

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, for-loop, pymongo

I have multiple lists of dictionaries in Python in the format [dic1, dic2, dic3,..., dicx]

I'm trying to insert these dictionaries as a batch insert in mongodb:

```
(pseudocode)
db.batch.insert_many(dic1, dic2,...,dicx)
```

but because each of the arrays are of variable length, I think I need to a for loop, but can't visualize how to do so exactly.

Comment: Is `batch.insert()` a function you defined?

Comment: @AnandSKumar and all python people. He is "pseudocoing" for an actual pymongo method which is `.insert()` on a `collection` object. The `db` can be expressed that way as well. So where `db` is the database that is how pymongo can call the method.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Looks like the batch method for pymongo for mongodb 3.0+ is insert_many().

Comment: @SLee yes it as as I was answering at the time. `.insert()` is also a method, but it's singular. And generally accepted to be replaced with `.insert_one()` in recent drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the function db.batch.insert() can take a variable number of arguments, you can use the * operator in front of the lists. Consider the simple print function:

```
>>> words = ["dog","cat","mouse"]
>>> print(*words)
dog cat mouse
```

print(*words) is thus equivalent to print("dog","cat","mouse")

Comment: Yead `db.batch.insert()` is a real method used by pymogo with MongoDB. Which is what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you connected to MongoDB and grabbed your database something like this:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.test
```

Then if your collection is indeed called "batch" you can use the [`.insert_many()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) method which accepts an array of dict:

```
listOfDict = [dict1,dict2,dict3]

db.batch.insert_many(listOfDict)
```